# How Can I Cancel LengthyOperation In WindowProc

Tags: windows, win32gui, peekmessage

I Have Read An MSDN Article And Completely Confused:

```
HWND hwnd; 
BOOL fDone; 
MSG msg; 

// Begin the operation and continue until it is complete 
// or until the user clicks the mouse or presses a key. 

fDone = FALSE; 
while (!fDone) 
{ 
 fDone = DoLengthyOperation(); // application-defined function 



while (PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
{ 
    switch(msg.message) 
    { 
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: 
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: 
        case WM_KEYDOWN: 
            // 
            // Perform any required cleanup. 
            // 
            fDone = TRUE; 
    } 
} 
}
```

MSDN Says With This Code We Can **examine the message queue during a lengthy operation** & cancel it In Case Of Mouse Click Or Keyboard KeyDown.
how thishappend?

when DoLengthyOperation starts does not returned until it finished and PeekMessage does not call in this time and cant cancel the operation.

msdn link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928

Comment: Supposedly the function returns *false* for a while, indicating that the lengthy operation is not done yet.  The key is to break up one long operation into many smaller ones.

Comment: you must not call `DoLengthyOperation();` in *GUI* thread - need call it in separate working thread. until `DoLengthyOperation();` executed in your code example - you not call `PeekMessage` so and not got any windows messages at all and your UI is freeze

Comment: @HansPassant if function returns false for a while, in next call how function continue from last line of code that executed in previous call? in next call function run from first line again

Comment: @RbMm if DoLengthyOperation(); calls in another thread, there were no need to peekMessage loop in that way,DoLengthyOperation() calls in same thread.

Comment: It is just a conceptual code snippet, not a practical one.  You normally need an InitializeLengthyOperation() function to, say, initialize a counter.  And a CancelLengthyOperation() to cleanup.   Keep in mind that you don't write code like this very often, albeit that the traditional game loop resembles this.  This snippet was surely included to remind programmers that it is important to keep the UI thread of a program responsive to user input.  That it is.

Comment: @AlirezaKhalesi - are you not understand that while `DoLengthyOperation();` will execute - you not handle windows messages and ui is freeze ? you can not break `DoLengthyOperation();` by message because you not peek messages while it execute. of how suggest Hans Passant - you need break `DoLengthyOperation();` to smaller short functions

Comment: @HansPassant got it,thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking for, you need to peek the message queue from inside of `DoLengthyOperation()` itself, eg:

```
BOOL fDone = FALSE; 
do
{ 
    fDone = DoLengthyOperation();
} 
while (!fDone);

...

BOOL DoLengthyOperation()
{
    MSG msg; 

    ...

    if (PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE) ||
        PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE)) 
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        return TRUE;
    } 

    ...

    if (PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST, PM_REMOVE) ||
        PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE)) 
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        return TRUE;
    } 

    ...

    return FALSE;
}
```

Otherwise, you should move the lengthy operation to a separate worker thread instead, don't block the main UI message queue at all.  When the main message loop receives mouse/keyboard input normally, you can then signal the thread to terminate itself if it is running.